# Why Normal and Local Orientation is not the same?

Tags: modeling, normals, axis

Why do the normal and local of the top face of the cube not have the same orientation?
Here's the normal orientation of the top face of the cube:[image]

And here's the local orientation of the top face of the cube
[image]

I have done zero transformations to the cube, so they should be the same right? Why the difference?

Comment: Is this a cube added with shift+a or the default cube?  Iirc there is a small difference in the order of the vertices